# Area51 vs Area51 discussion

Tags: support, area-51

I have opened an `Area51` account, and I don't get the difference between it to `Area51 discussion`. I noticed that there is the `Area51` and `Area51 discussion` where I get different badges. I also have seen that there are 2 different faqs.  By now I have a question that got 2 up-votes, but the reputation is still 151 (probably will get updated soon). So my questions:

- Do I have different reputations in `Area51` and `Area51 discussion`?
- Why do I have different badges?
- Are these considered different sites? (like `StackOverflow` and `Meta-StackOverflow`)
- Any other main differences between the tow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Area51 Discussion is basically the Meta site for Area51. Your reputation is taken from the main site like any other per-site Meta, but badges are awarded separately for actions you complete there (they're completely different than on the main site), also like any other per-site Meta.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. So what you are saying is that questions in the discussion won't affect my reputation? (I have never looked into this at any site before)

Comment: No, they won't.